# how remove all the taxes from cart in woocommerce programmatically

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I have following scenario.

If customer book product one one day than NO GST and Other Tax should apply. How do I display or override tax on cart page using code from function file in woocommerce.

[Please have a loogk at image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fEFq1.png)

I want to Set "TPS(0%)"..

NOTE: TPS is GST here

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

have you try to change the tax TPS value from 5% to 0%?

go to: woocommerce > settings > tax > Standard taxes and change the tax %.

Let me know.

Comment: I cannot do that as I want to change it dynamically. I achieved it by following line: $cart_item['data']->set_tax_class( 'Zero rate' ); I thank you for your response.